# Laravel insert relationship in newly created model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a relationship set up between two models. The two models are set up like:

**app/Character.php**

```
public function characteristics() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Characteristics');
}
```

**app/Characteristics.php**

```
public function character() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Character');
}
```

then in a controller I have a method to create a new character with a predetermined set of characteristics as follows:

**app/Http/Controllers/CharacterController.php**

```
public function newCharacter(Request $request) {
    $character = new Character();  
    $characteristics = getCharacteristics($character->id);
    // Save basic character stuff
    $character->characteristics()->saveMany($characteristics);
    $character->save();
}
```

The highlighted line is throwing an error because `saveMany` is not a function of `Builder` so how can I get the created character without having to do a `find` that would have to hit the database again?

Comment: Are you looking for `associate`?

Comment: What does `getCharacteristics()` return? Is it an array of Characteristics models?

Comment: Sorry guys I went to dinner directly after. `getCharacteristics` does return an array of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to save the character model first, because if you're building a hasMany/belongsTo relationship your characteristics table must have a column for character_id, and when you do `$character->characteristics()->saveMany($characteristics);` Laravel will try to insert the ID from the parent model. And as per the code shared by you, you've just instantiated the model, by this point of time it doesn't have an ID associated with it. So you need to save the character model first and assuming the `getCharacteristics()` method is returning an array/collection of Characteristics Models, Following should work:

```
public function newCharacter(Request $request) {
    $character = new Character();
    $character->save();
    $characteristics = getCharacteristics();
    // Save basic character stuff
    $character->characteristics()->saveMany($characteristics);
}
```

And to further clarify this for you, from the characteristics method in your Character model an instance of `HasMany` not a `Builder` is being returned, thus saveMany works here.

Comment: I made these changes (updating the question now) and it still has the same error.

Comment: as per the errror you're trying to call `characterstics()` while the method name defined in the model is `characteristics()` .. feels like the `missing i` is the one causing error..

Comment: Wow... thank you for being my 2nd pair of eyes there. I'm going to accept your answer as I believe reordering the code was still necessary.